# How to use CssSelectors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to test the ebay site login with out Xpath. but it is not working I tried so many hours . please explain me the error.
1.  Open Google website
2.  Search for “ebay” website
3.  Click on the appropriate result
4.  Go to http://www.ebay.com website
5.  Click on the “Sign in” link to navigate to the ebay login page
6.  Enter email address/password 
7.  Click on Sign In button
8.  Verify your user name.
     package Script;

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class TestEbay_login {
        @Test
        public void ebay_login() throws InterruptedException {

                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Senani\\Downloads\\Programs\\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new  FirefoxDriver();
                //driver.get("https://www.google.com");
                driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("ebay");
                driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).submit();
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='www.ebay.com']")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("#########");
                driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("###########");

                driver.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();


        }

    }
```

> FAILED: ebay_login org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: a[href='www.ebay.com'] For documentation on
>   this error, please visit:
>   https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? What is your usecase?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='www.ebay.com']")).click(); is not working. error occur there.

Comment: @xtratic thanx. but i cannot understand the error. it works with xpath. then i tried  without xpath. my testing fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you initiate the search you need to induce `WebDriverWait` for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
   ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://www.ebay.com/']"))
).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you're going to run into here:

First, while the *text* Google displays in the search results says the URL is `https://www.ebay.com`, the *actual* `href` of the `<a>` tag is an internal (gibberish) link used for tracking purposes. So, in my browser, the eBay result's `href` actually points to:

`/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjItIGq48_fAhWiSt8KHVHWCMUQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw2IUWs7JZelxpS-zydrZoSX`

...which of course then *redirects* to eBay's site.

The second problem you're going to have is that the CSS selector `a[href='www.ebay.com']` requires an *exact* match—that selector would *not* match a link that points to `https://www.ebay.com`.

EDIT: Digging into the HTML on the Google results page, it looks like the link in the *sidebar* actually does go straight to eBay.com. So, you could edit your CSS selector to be: `a[href='http://www.ebay.com']`

(Note that for reasons I'm not clear on, that sidebar link goes to the non-secure version of the eBay home page.)

Comment: And why the Google search instead of just going to `ebay.com` in the first place?